# Apple M1, Android emulator laggy and freezes

Tags: android-emulator, apple-m1

My Android emulator running on Apple M1 is very slow and laggy. It freezes often as well, especially when I try to use Chrome.

I believe I have the latest Android Emulator version installed as well. Not sure if anyone else is having this issue?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same issue with API 33, laggy and getting random crashes very annoying. `Emulator v32.1.12`, M2 base model. Someone should probably report this on https://issuetracker.google.com.